# Docker image works in macOS and doesnt work in Raspberry

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi4

I created a docker image and run it on macOS with `docker run --rm -d -p 80:80 myimage:latest` then i can load my project as `http://localhost`
To use this image in another machine, I copy this image as tar file and load it in raspberry pi machine, even thought it loads well and shows as `sudo docker images`, when i run it with same command: `sudo docker run --rm -d -p 80:80 myimage:latest` only returns hash number in terminal like macOS and doesnt load the page in browser

Answer (score 0):

That's because Mac's and Raspberry Pi's have different processor architectures - as such image built on one won't work on the other.

You need to either build te image on Raspberry Pi or set up yor Mac to create multi-arch builds (as described [here](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/)) and then copy the right build to the Pi.